# React API calls not working every time with proxy URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, fetch-api

I have a react front end making API calls to a Rails API only app.
I have the proxy configuration on package.json as follows:

```
 {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  **"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",**
  "dependencies": {
    "globalize": "^1.3.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.17.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-globalize": "^0.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.2.12",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.77.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I'm using fetch to retreive data form the Rails app:

```
export const eventsFetch = () => {
    //console.log('estoy en productsFetch!');
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: EVENTS_FETCHING });
        **window.fetch('api/v1/events')**
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
              dispatch({ type: EVENTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: response });
          })
          .catch(error => {
              dispatch({ type: EVENTS_FETCH_FAILURE, payload: error })
          })
    };
};

export const upcomingEventsFetch = (page = 1) => {
    //console.log('estoy en productsFetch!');
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: EVENTS_FETCHING });
        **window.fetch('api/v1/events/upcoming?page=' + page)**
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
              dispatch({ type: EVENTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: response });
          })
          .catch(error => {
              dispatch({ type: EVENTS_FETCH_FAILURE, payload: error })
          })
    };
};

export const detailedEventFetch = (eventId) => {
    //console.log('estoy en productsFetch!');
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: EVENTS_FETCHING });
        **window.fetch('api/v1/events/' + eventId)**
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
              dispatch({ type: EVENTS_FETCH_SUCCESS, payload: response });
          })
          .catch(error => {
              dispatch({ type: EVENTS_FETCH_FAILURE, payload: error })
          })
    };
};
```

Out of these 3 API calls, the firs 2 works fine, they make the api call to http://localhost:3001/api/v1/...

But the third one, is sending the request to http://localhost:3001/events/api/v1/...
It is adding the events path, which is the client path as per the ReactRouterDom configuration:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './Header';
import EventsCalendar from './EventsCalendar';
import EventDetail from './EventDetail';
import Footer from './Footer';
import NavMenu from './NavMenu';

// The Main component renders one of the three provided
// Routes (provided that one matches). Both the /roster
// and /schedule routes will match any pathname that starts
// with /roster or /schedule. The / route will only match
// when the pathname is exactly the string "/"
const Main = () => (
  <main>
    <NavMenu>
      {/* <Header/> */}
      <Switch>
        **<Route exact path='/events' component={ EventsCalendar } />
        <Route path='/events/:eventId' component={ EventDetail } />**
      </Switch>
      </NavMenu>
      <Footer />
    
  </main>
)

export default Main
```

Can anyone help me out on how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to concat your entire url first then place that inside the fetch? Concat it before, then console.log it, just to make sure your fetching what you think. My best guess is id might have letters or something other than numbers?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the full path? You could set the API url as env variable and then just concat the full string. `API_URL + 'api/v1/events/' + eventId`

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your comments, I did try using the full URL, but I received a Cross Origin error. I'm gessing is because of the different port from the client and the server.